Using pam_mount under Ubuntu Studio 24.04 LTS
After successfully using pam_mount to automatically mount AD server directories for domain users in Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS, I am trying to reproduce this success in a fresh installation of Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS.
Here is a sample line from /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml for one of the shares that mounted under Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS but doesn't mount under Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS:
<volume sgrp="domain users@nas.rsbrux.ch" fstype="cifs" server="diskstation.nas.rsbrux.ch" path="private" mountpoint="/nas/private" options="sec=krb5,cruid=%(USERUID),noexec,rw,nofail" />

/var/log/auth.log contains several errors of the form:
(systemd): PAM unable to dlopen(pam_mount.so): /usr/lib/security/pam_mount.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(systemd): PAM adding faulty module: pam_mount.so

Not only does the file /usr/lib/security/pam_mount.so not exist, there isn't even a directory /usr/lib/security/.
Any ideas as to what might be missing or wrong and how to fix it would be most welcome.
Failing that, perhaps someone could point me to a pam_mount tutorial which includes command-line examples.  The man pages for pam_mount say,

To ensure that your system and, possibly, the remote server are all properly configured, you should try to mount all or some of the volumes by hand, using the same commands and mount points provided in pam_mount.conf.xml. This will save you a lot of grief, since it is more difficult to debug the mounting process via pam_mount.

Is there a "pam_mount" command, or does this refer to regular "mount" commands?

The answer was embarrassingly simple: libpam-mount had not been installed.  After running:
sudo apt install libpam-mount cifs-utils

everything works as expected.
